# How to disable keyboard shortcut list on holding Super key?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

Using CompizConfiguration Settings Manager (CCSM), I've assigned hold <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Roll mouse</kbd> button to zoom in/out.

When I hold <kbd>Super</kbd> key it by default shows shortcut list on Ubuntu 12.04. I want these two process (e.g. zoom in and appearance of the shortcut list) not to occur simultaneously.

I did not find any useful tip on Google.

Comment: My advice is not to fiddle with keyboard shortcuts. It's _possible_ that, sooner or later, some thing will conflict.

Comment: Yes, your'e right @vasa1 but I disable shortcut list on pressing super key for the time being. Zooming opting is more important to me for the time being. Secondly, I can roll back all the changes made in Compiz, if I encounter any shortcut-keys related trouble in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either change the launcher key:

```
CCSM -> Unity Plugin -> Behaviour Tab -> "key to show launcher"
```

or disable shortcuts list:

```
CCSM -> Unity Plugin -> Experimental Tab -> "Enable Shortcuts Hints Overlay"
```

Comment: The second method is sufficient to achieve it.